# Animsition jQuery plugin for CSS animated page transitions vs jquery Masonry

Tags: jquery, transition, jquery-masonry, animsition

I'm building a multi page site, and really love the page transition effect that the plugin Animsition allows. However on a page I used the jquery Masonry plugin. When I first open this page the layout is fine, but when I navigate to other pages of the site and return to the one that's using Masonry the layout is broken. Can anyone help... please

Comment: Please provide your code and a jsfiddle. How can we possibly help without knowing anything about your code?

Comment: you can see what I mean by following this  test link: http://webdpix.com/citycos/funcionamento.html

Comment: Actually It is not apparent. What pages are you specifically having issues with? You need to be more specific in your question and description.

Comment: When I open http://webdpix.com/citycos/funcionamento.html the layout is fine. When I navigate to other pages, and open again funcionamento.html the layout where I call masonry, becomes broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [imagesloaded.js](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) which will make all images load before masonry is called. Load it in your page and then call masonry like this:

```
 $(function () {
 $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 300,
    gutter: 20  
        });
    });
 });
```

Also, a separate issue, "js/jquery.scrollToTop.min.js" is not loaded.